# Dynamically Caclulated Values with Entity Field Query

Tags: entities, database

Is there any way to query by dynamically calculated values using Entity Field Query? Take the following:

I want to query where the sum of `field_some_number` and a user-provided variable are greater than or equal to 5. Right now I'm only able to do the following:

```
$my_variable = -7;    
$query->fieldCondition('field_some_number', 'value', 5, '>=');
```

But obviously this doesn't include my user-provided variable. How can I calculate this on the fly? Could `hook-query-alter` help me with this? I have not been able to figure out how to properly implement it. I'm using this with the Restful-Drupal module.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Entity Query supports expression.

- In your case, I think you might not even need it as you can workaround.

  $value_to_compare = 5 - $user_provided_value;
  $query->fieldCondition('field_some_number', 'value', $value_to_compare, '>=');
- But if you need to compute value based on columns of database table, you can go ahead with db_select, where you can have addExpression for calculation.

  $query->addExpression('table_columns_1 + table_columns_2', 'sum');
  $query->having('sum', 5,'>=');

Comment: Makes sense, was hoping to stick with EFQ. Also, my example might not have been the best, but imagine you wanted a more complex query where `field_some_number * field_another_number >= 50`. Is there any way to combine `db_select` with EFQ or do I need a totally new query?

Comment: total new query